# Does tornado spawn a new process upon receiving a request?

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I am using Tornado server with a Python Flask app. For each request, a whole bunch of data is analyzed and the results are output. However, in a few days, the RAM (50GB) fills up. Not sure why that is happening.

Is it that once a request is received, Tornado spawns a new process which does the analysis, delivers the output and then dies. Or is it that it will analyze the data in the same process and the variables created during it would keep lurking even after the response has been delivered. If it is the latter, that could explain the RAM filling up. My code:

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug=True
    http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
    http_server.listen(5000)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

top output:
[image: top output]

Comment: In addition to @Juca's answer, which process is filling the memory? What do you do in your app? Probably a global variable is growing bigger and bigger.

Comment: @onurgüngör there are no global variables. The app gets some search details from the user, process text based on it (~100MB) and then outputs the analysis. Regarding what is filling up the memory, not sure! Doing "top" shows 50% memory used on the top bar where memory is mentioned but only 20% when I sum up the %MEM of processes

Comment: I suspect you're looking at the wrong location, can you post the output of `top`?

Comment: @onurgüngör Have edited my question with top output. Also, link to the photo: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NTrJn.png

Comment: We can see that the process which consumes memory is `java`, not `python`. So your problem is probably not related with Tornado.

Comment: Thanks but it says java is taking 9.6% `mem`? Why do `%mem` and 'virt' not match?

Comment: Also, when I reboot the system, the `virt` immediately goes to 32g however the memory used on top is only a couple of GBs. But over time, the memory used number keeps going up but java's `virt` stays at 32g and `%mem` at ~9%

Comment: A process can map as much as it wants so it's normal. I am not capable of saying the exact amount but it's basically limited by your architecture, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11295206/645853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, tornado does not spawn a new process every request

Comment: Thanks. So does that mean it does everything in the same process and variables created in a previous request would still hang around in the RAM after the request has been served?

Comment: The same process yes, the same variables don't (depends on what you are doing, of course). Every request a new instance of RequestHandler is created